# How does a websocket client 'break'?

Tags: websocket

I'm trying to understand what happens when a websocket client receives data very rapidly, so that it starts malfunctioning.

For example, if the client receives thousands of messages per second, I assume that messages get written to a buffer, hence if I read slowly, it starts breaking.

I'm looking for information on some libraries and how they implement websockets.